# Fetching tweets from twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I want to fetch tweets from IPL official page and display in my android app..How should I proceed in this?I have never used twitter in android before..I searched on internet and found various articles relating to create twitter login but couldn't find study material relating to fetching tweets from particular page in twitter  in android..I would be thankful if someone can just tell me steps the way I should proceed on this?

Answer (score 0):

i have used [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/archive/twitter4j-4.0.2.zip)  Library for twitter

Twitter4J is an unofficial Java library for the Twitter API.
With Twitter4J, you can easily integrate your Java application with the Twitter service. Twitter4J is an unofficial library.

Twitter4J is featuring:

- 100% Pure Java - works on any Java Platform version 5 or later
- Android platform and Google App Engine ready
- Zero dependency : No additional jars required
- Built-in OAuth support
- Out-of-the-box gzip support
- 100% Twitter API 1.1 compatible

and folow dome twitter4j example http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: Thankss..Suppose I want to fetch tweets from particular twitter page https://twitter.com/IPL and diplay in my android app..There is no statement in this example where we are giving uri of particular page or blog from where i can fetch tweets..

Comment: yes you can use in android also and i have also use in my app :)

Comment: thanks..can u tell me the code statemnt where we provide a particular uri example.twitter.com/IPL to fetch tweets from particulat page..?i can't find any such statemnt in that example

Comment: i have fetch twits like List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(IPL,paging);

Comment: i have found the following link http://www.sitepoint.com/loading-twitter-data-into-android-with-lists/ which explains loading data from twitter in android app..Should i follow these steps and replace HttpGet("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=android"); with uri from where i want to fetch tweets ?

Comment: yaeh its good tutorial its not use twitter4J this will useful only fetch twits if you want login and other option than its not useful so use library OW as your requirement

Comment: yeah..i just want to fetch tweets from ipl official page and display in my android app..for that i think this tutorial is nice..  +1 from my side for ur answer..

Comment: Hii ..i have followed this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_twitter_integration.htm and integrated Twitter4J library into my project..This allows your application to connect to twitter and share data or any kind of updates on twitter..But I want to fetch tweets from a particular page on twitter in my android app..Can u pzz suggest me code for that..U wrote - List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(IPL,paging); ..here should I replace IPL with uri for twitter IPL page..